# Symfony2 Choice Form Data from ORM

Tags: symfony

Have this form:

```
class ScanType extends AbstractType
{
        public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
        {
                $builder->add('scantarget', 'entity', array(
                                        'class' => 'AppBundle:Website',
                                        'property' => 'url'
                                        ));
        }


        public function getDefaultOptions(array $options) {
        return array(
            'data_class' => 'AppBundle\Entity\Website',
        );
    }


}
```

Need to populate it with only urls for the particular userid

In the controller:

```
         /**
         * @Route("/verification-ok", name="verifyurlok")
         */
        public function verifyurlActionOK(Request $request)
        {
                $user = $this->getUser();



                if($user)
                {
                        $userid=$user->getId();

                        $websites = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('AppBundle:Website')->findByUser($userid);


                        $form = $this->createForm(ScanType::class, $websites);
```

However, the $websites is not passed properly to FormBuilder and in my Select box I see all entries :( All possible values for Website entity.

How to Display only passed $websites in the form (select box)? So only websites for a specific userid?

Thanks,

**Update 1**

Form

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Form;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\EmailType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\TextType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\RepeatedType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\PasswordType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\ChoiceType;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Token\Storage\TokenStorageInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormEvent;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormEvents;

class ScanType extends AbstractType
{

private $tokenStorage;

    public function __construct(TokenStorageInterface $tokenStorage)
    {
                $this->tokenStorage = $tokenStorage;
    }

    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
                $user = $this->tokenStorage->getToken()->getUser();
                if (!$user) {
                   throw new \LogicException(
                   'The FriendMessageFormType cannot be used without an authenticated user!'
                   );
                }


                $builder->addEventListener(
                FormEvents::PRE_SET_DATA,
                function (FormEvent $event) use ($user) {
                $form = $event->getForm();

                $formOptions = array(
                    'class' => 'AppBundle\Entity\Website',
                    'property' => 'user',
                    'query_builder' => function (EntityRepository $er) use ($user) {
                        // build a custom query
                        return $er->createQueryBuilder('u')->addOrderBy('user', 'DESC');

                        // or call a method on your repository that returns the query builder
                        // the $er is an instance of your UserRepository
                        // return $er->createOrderByFullNameQueryBuilder();
                    },
                );

                // create the field, this is similar the $builder->add()
                // field name, field type, data, options
                $form->add('url', ScanType::class, $formOptions);
            }
        );
    }


        public function getDefaultOptions(array $options) {
        return array(
            'data_class' => 'AppBundle\Entity\Website',
        );
    }


}
```

Controller:

```
 $form = $this->createForm(ScanType::class);
```

config.yml

```
services:
    app.form.scan:
        class: AppBundle\Form\ScanType
        arguments: ['@security.token_storage']
        tags:
            - { name: form.type }
```

Unfortunately, get this error:

```
request.CRITICAL: Uncaught PHP Exception Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\Exception\UndefinedOptionsException: "The options "class", "property", "query_builder" do not exist. Defined options are: "action", "allow_extra_fields", "attr", "auto_initialize", "block_name", "by_reference",
```

**Solution:**

Thanks @Medard

Form:

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Form;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\EmailType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\TextType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\RepeatedType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\PasswordType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\ChoiceType;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolverInterface;

class ScanType extends AbstractType
{      
            private $websites;


            public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
            {
                    $this->websites = $options['trait_choices'];

                    $builder->add('scantarget', 'entity', array(
                          'class' => 'AppBundle:Website',
                          'property' => 'url',
                          'choices' => $this->websites
                        ));
            }


           public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
           {
                    $resolver->setDefaults(array(
                         'data_class' => null,
                         'trait_choices' => null,

                        ));
           }


}
```

Controller:

```
 $form = $this->createForm(ScanType::class, $websites, array(
        'trait_choices' => $websites
    ));
```

Works!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you are not setting the choices. Try this:

```
   class ScanType extends AbstractType
    {      
            private $websites;


            public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
            {
              $this->websites = $options['trait_choices'];

                    $builder->add('scantarget', 'entity', array(
                          'class' => 'AppBundle:Website',
                          'property' => 'url',
                          'choices' => $this->websites
                        ));
            }


            public function setDefaultOptions(array $options) {
            return array(
                'data_class' => 'AppBundle\Entity\Website',
                'trait_choices' => null,
            );
        }


    }
```

In the controller pass through the websites:

```
$form = $this->createForm(ScanType::class, $websites, array(
        'trait_choices' => $websites,
    ));
```

Comment: this won't work as is, it will trigger an exception because no data is pushed in constructor in his controller. Plus this is not the good way to perform what is needed

Comment: Sorry, that was for symfony 2, I have edited my answer

Comment: Thanks! hmmm ... I need it form Symfony2 (2.8) ... unfortunately it does not work ... request.CRITICAL: Uncaught PHP Exception Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\Exception\UndefinedOptionsException: "The option "websites" does not exist. Defined options are: "action", "allow_extra_fields" etc etc

Comment: Sorry about that. Try changing 'websites' to 'trait_choices' as I have done above

Comment: Still the same error. Now it says: request.CRITICAL: Uncaught PHP Exception Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\Exception\UndefinedOptionsException: "The option "trait_choices" does not exist. Defined options are: "action", "allow_extra_fields"

Comment: It should be setDefaultOptions instead of getDefaultOptions

Comment: OK Works. Had to modify it a little bit, see Solution 1 update in my post. Thanks @Medard

Answer (score 0):

Your form displays all the Website entries because you're not restricting them when building the form, in the add() method.

You should read this section fo the cookbook : http://symfony.com/doc/current/form/dynamic_form_modification.html#form-events-user-data

Comment: Thanks. Can you see my Update 1. I updated it with my code. Unfortunately, I get an error with query_builder. How can I resolve this? Any ideas?

Comment: Actually with 3 options ...  The options "class", "property", "query_builder"  do not exist